# Generating a datatable from a dictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-structures, dictionary, datatable

I'm currently developing a .NET WinForms application that reads 8 csv files of the same format and stores the data of each CSV file in an object with methods for modification/retrieval of data.

Each row of the CSV file has data about a policy.

The structure of the classes/objects I'm using is this:

`Policy`
This class/object stores all the data related to a single policy, i.e. one row of the CSV file. This class has a member called `polData` which is an `OrderedDictionary`. `polData` stores each field as a string with the field header as the key.

`DataFile`
This class/object stores all the data read from a csv file, i.e. every policy. This class has a member called `polCollection` which is an `OrderedDictionary`. `polCollection` stores all the policy objects using the policy ID as the key.

For both classes, I've used an `OrderedDictionary` because I need to preserve the order in which the data is added to the dictionary.

Once these objects have been created and populated, I need to output one of them to a `datagridview`. Therefore, I want to create a `DataTable` using the data in the dictionary. Please find below my approach. My instint is that there is a more efficient approach so I'd appreciate any feedback:

In the `DataFile` class, I have the following method:

```
 Public Function toDataTable() As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim fieldHeader As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pol As Policy

    '//add columns to datatable
    '//there are 68 columns. 
    '//the calcFieldHeader function returns the header string based on the header index
    For i = 0 To 67
        fieldHeader = tools.calcFieldHeader(i)
        dt.Columns.Add(fieldHeader)
    Next i

    '//loop through each policy in polCollection
    '//add policy rows to datatable
    For Each key In polCollection.keys
        pol = polCollection(key)
        dt.Rows.Add(pol.toArray)
    Next key

    Return dt

End Function
```

In the `Policy`class, I have the following method:

```
 Public Function toArray() As String()
    Dim result(67) As String
    Dim inx As Integer
    inx = 0

    For Each key In polData.keys
        result(inx) = polData(key).ToString
        inx = inx + 1
    Next (key)

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: You could dispense with the step of creating those dictionaries and move the CSV data directly into the Datatables, using those datatables as the store, rather than dictionaries, thereby avoiding the redundancy, which is more "efficient". There is a TextFieldParser that can read CSV files in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace. You could use a column in the DataTable to store a value representing the data order in any case. The Dictionaries are unncecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use dictionaries. Parse the CSV directly into the datatable.

```
Private Function csvToDatatable(files As List(Of String), Optional skipxLines As Integer = 0) As DataTable

    Dim vbReader As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    'loop through the files from the list
    For Each filePath In files

        If File.Exists(filePath) Then

            'keep track of lineCount for each file
            Dim lineCount As Integer = 1

            'setup TextFieldParser for CSV
            vbReader = New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(filePath)
            vbReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            vbReader.SetDelimiters(",")

            While Not vbReader.EndOfData

                Try
                    'read each line item
                    Dim currentRow = vbReader.ReadFields()

                    'Option skip x lines incase there are header records
                    If lineCount > skipxLines Then

                        'set generic columns using count of fields
                        If dt.Columns.Count = 0 Then
                            For i = 0 To UBound(currentRow)
                                dt.Columns.Add("Column" & i.ToString)
                            Next
                        Else

                            If UBound(currentRow) <> dt.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                                'check to make sure array of fields is the same size as data columns
                                Throw New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException

                            End If

                        End If
                        'add row with data from currentRow array
                        dt.Rows.Add(currentRow)

                    End If

                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    MsgBox("Line " & lineCount & " in file " & filePath & " is not valid and will be skipped.")
                End Try

                lineCount += 1

            End While

        End If

    Next

    Return dt

End Function
```

Use of this function would look like this.

```
Dim fileList As New List(Of String)

fileList.Add("C:\exports\texting.csv")
fileList.Add("C:\exports\texting2.csv")

theGrid.DataSource = csvToDatatable(fileList, 1)
theGrid.DataBind()
```

In this example I'm assuming header records are present.